# How can I show sidebar icons at the same time as the flutter back button?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project in Flutter. I have a back button and on the right I have a text button and a sidebar. They just don't appear at the same time. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    endDrawer: Drawer(child:AppDrawer(super.widget)),
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
      ),
      title: Text('Text Controller'),
      actions: [
        TextButton(onPressed: (){print('press');}, child: Text('Press')),
      ],
```

[and this is image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGzsO.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. what do you mean that they don't "appear at the same time"? Are you using some kind of animation?

Comment: No, I don't use animotion. Check image please. The text button and the sidebar button are not visible at the same time, only the text button is visible. I want both to appear at the same time.